# Confusions about Israel's paper on junctions / singular shells in GR

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, differential-geometry, boundary-conditions

After reading [Israel's well-known paper](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF02710419) superficially (see also the [erratum](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007%2FBF02712210.pdf)) I thought that his formulas (38)-(40) were necessary and sufficient conditions to join two manifolds along a time-like surface inhabited by a singular shell of dust. Also his example (coupling Minkowski to Schwarzschild) seems to suggest so. However, if you would believe this, you would derive the following corrollary: If the first fundamental forms (i.e. intrinsic geometry) of the surface agrees on both sides and if by chance those surfaces are a [geodesic congruence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Congruence_(general_relativity)) on both sides (we're gluing geodesics on one side to geodesics on the other side) then all terms in his equations of motion (38)-(40) are individually zero and these equations are trivially satisfied. Eq. (40) then tells us moreover that, in addition, there is no singular dust on the gluing surface. So I first thought "Oh nice, so this is a 'higher order' surface (see section 4 of the paper) and I just found an easy method to create those".

However, I found out recently that I must be mistaken: gluing geodesic congruences together doesn't seem to ensure that the extrinsic curvature is going to agree on both sides of the gluing (as is required in the [Darmois boundary condition](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF00766295) and as you would expect to be the case for "higher-order" or "boundary" surfaces).

**Q1: What are the physical objections against gluing together along time-like geodesic congruences (whose intrinsic geometry agrees)?** (*)

**Q2: Is Israel's paper still considered 'correct' or 'relevant'? How should I read it?** (**)(***)

(*) I know already that the contractions $T_{\mu\nu}n^{\mu}n^{\nu}$ and $T_{\mu\nu}e_i^{\mu}n^{\nu}$ should also have the same value on both sides of the surface: no net absoprtion of fluid onto the surface.

(**) I often read that nowadays, Israel's result are considered equivalent to the Darmois boundary conditions.

(***) In my opinion, the author is sloppy to indicate which derivations/calculations are equivalences as opposed to one-way implications.